# Print message into R markdown console while knitting

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm wondering if there is a way to print a message containing one of the variables into Rmarkdown console at the end of knitting?

I'm currently preparing an R Markdown template for others to use. I would like to inform the users about the readability index of the document once it finishes compiling. I have already found a way to calculate it in one of the chunks. Now I would like to automatically print it to the person who compiles it in a way that it is not shown in the final document. Any ideas?

Comment: *might* work to add a chunk with `message=FALSE` in the chunk options and then call `message()` within the chunk?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ben Bolkers comment is the perfect answer. I ended up putting:

```
{r cache = FALSE, echo = F, warning = F, message = F}
message(rdblty)
```

at the very bottom of the markdown file. `rdblty` is the variable calculated before that I wanted to print out.

Answer (score 3):

How about ?

```
    cat(file="readability.txt")
```

Comment: using the `message = FALSE` didnt do what I wanted but this worked.